# Is there any alternative to Stripe PG when publishing on salesforce apps market?

Tags: administration

I've read a lot comments on how it sucks to work with stripe.com so now I'm a bit concerned if there is any alternative to Stripe Payment Gateway when publishing on Salesforce Apps Market?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any gateway that accepts a web services call or REST call, and any such calls should also be encrypted via HTTPS (TLS). I have personally integrated with Authorize.net and PayPal, but you can use almost any payment gateway on the Internet as long as it meets those basic criteria.

As a side note, you should probably compare several services anyways, even stripe.com, and make your own educated decision, rather than going by hearsay. Choosing just one service based on a recommendation without comparing for yourself can be a costly mistake.

Comment: Sounds like Salesforce is bound with Stripe.com according this link https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout. Still it's not clear how to use other payment processors on appexchange.

Comment: @AndrewG That's salesforce.com's "out of the box" payment solution; there's no API development involved, as all the heavy lifting has already been implemented for you (and is automatically built into the system). You're free to collect your payments using any other alternative method, but you won't get that automatic integration that you get if you use AppExchange Checkout (e.g. automatic license updating/renewal, etc).